F. Mandl writes that change in the fundamental thermodynamic equation $dE=TdS-pdV$ need NOT be reversible. Is it wrong？
Principles of theremodynamics for irreversible processes clearly state that the entropy changes satisfy relation $dS>dQ/T$. Thus we in general have for a irrevesible thermodynamic process $dE+pdV=dQ<TdS$, i.e.，$dE<TdS-pdV$. Why F Mandl stresses that change in the fundamental thermodynamic equation $dE=TdS-pdV$ need not be reversible in his famous textbook "statistical physics" (2nd Ed.) p.112?


It's kind-of wrong. It applies to all reversible paths, but only to the difference between the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states of an reversible irreversible path if these two end states are very closely neighboring to one another in phase space.

It's kind-of wrong.  It applies to all reversible paths, but only to the difference between the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states of an irreversible path if these two end states are very closely neighboring to one another in phase space.

Those relations hold when the process passes the system through equilibrium states; in this process, $E$ is a function of $S,V$.
This does not imply the process is reversible, because process being thermodynamically reversible means it can be (macroscopically) reverted by an infinitesimal change of external constraints, and the system then retraces the past macrostates. This means that both the system and its environment have to be in equilibrium and not produce entropy. The mere fact the process passes the system through equilibrium states does not imply it can be so easily reverted, or that it is in equilibrium with the environment.
For example, when heating a system inside a vessel by a source of heat of much higher temperature, but only weakly enough via a thick wall, so the system inside passes through equilibrium states, then in the wall (which is not part of the system in this consideration), in the wall, we have gradient of temperature, and entropy production. Thus the system is not in equilibrium with the heat source or the heat mediator far from the contact surface, and thus the process is thermodynamically irreversible. At the same time, the relation $dE=TdS-pdV$ holds, because the system passes through equilibrium states.

The relation $dE = T dS - pdV$ is a statement about the (linearized) internal energy change between neighbor equilibrium states. It contains only functions of the initial and final equilibrium states and is therefore independent of the process.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 The process has to be quasistatic and $S,T,p$ have to exist for this formula to hold. If the process is strongly non-equilibrium process, this formula is invalid.

You are insisting on a process. It might be necessary to define (measure) $U(S,V)$. But once you get it, it is possible to calculate its differential, aka the variation of $U$ between two neighbor points in the $P$,$V$ plane. Because $U$ is a function of the state, such variation, expressed as a function of properties at the initial and final states, is process-independent. Of course, such properties must exist, but the initial and final states are equilibrium states, and everything is well-defined. The subtle point, in my opinion, is not that there is a constraint on the differential form ...

...but that only for reversible processes we can claim that  the differential $dE$ corresponds to the variation of internal energy $\Delta E$. I.e., it is $\Delta E$ process dependent.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 The question is why Mandl says the infinitesimal change need not be reversible. This can only be explained in terms of the whole physical process involving the environment, which need not be thermodynamically reversible. I do not see your point at all - of course if we restrict the system states to plane $pV$ (equilibrium states), then $dU$ does not depend on path in this plane, and $dU$ is change of internal energy. This does not mean the process is reversible; all this holds also for irreversible processes, such as the example I gave.

My point is that an infinitesimal change of a function of state can be evaluated from the differential of a state function without introducing a process at any level. I see that an isochoric process implies that $q$ does not depend on the process. The way to understand this situation is to recall that the relation between heat and entropy variation is $q=T\Delta S$ only for reversible processes. This last relation fails, not the expression for the differential of $E$, which is a bare mathematical fact.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I still do not see how this is relevant; isochoric process is restricted to constant $V$, but the question does not have such restriction. And what is there to understand about $q$ not depending on process? Of course, for such restricted process, net accepted heat is function of internal energy, because volume work is zero, so $q=\Delta U$.

And I disagree regarding the relation $q=T\Delta S$, this relation holds for any isothermal process during which the system is in equilibrium macrostate with $T$ and other quantities defined, and also $dU = TdS - pdV$ holds then. Validity of these relations does not require the process to be thermodynamically reversible, it only requires that the system is in equilibrium macrostate at all stages of the process.

Maybe we're using "valid" in a different sense. In mathematical sense those relations are always valid (in $pV$ space or similar), but I use "valid" in physical sense,  that is, when the actual values of $dU$ or $dQ$ in real process can be expressed using those expressions (only in quasistatic processes where the systems passes through equilibrium states).

All of the variables in the equation $dE=TdS-pdV$ are system properties. Thus, infinitesimal changes in system properties between equilibrium states are independent of the process between the states. Therefore the equation applies to the system for an irreversible process as well as a reversible process.
In the equation $dS\gt \delta Q/T$, $Q$ is not a system property and $dS$ is the total charge in entropy of the system plus the surroundings for an irreversible process, which is greater than that for a reversible process. $dS$ of the system alone is defined for a reversible transfer of heat and is therefore, for any process, $dS_{sys}=\delta Q_{rev}/T$.
Hope this helps.

It can’t apply to all points (states) along an irreversible path, since the intermediate states are not equilibrium states and the temperature and pressure may not even be uniform.

@ChetMiller So dE is not independent of the process?

The change in every state function is independent of the process and depends only on the two end states.

@ChetMiller So... your answer is dE is independent of the process?

Sure, it only depends on the two closely neighboring end states.

@ChetMiller So then what  is "it" that "can't apply to all points (states)" ?

I'm trying to determine how I should reword my answer to be correct, in your eyes.

What I’m trying to say is that, far an irreversible path, the equation only applies to the two end states, an then only if they are very close to one another.  The irreversible path does not have to be direct; I’m thinking of a very long and tortuous path.

@ChetMiller So are you saying you disagree with the "Fundamental thermodynamic relations"  quote from Mandl ?

I’m saying that they don’t apply at each and every point along an irreversible path

@ChetMiller Can I take that as a "yes" to my question?

I disagree with the last sentence of your first paragraph.

@ChetMiller My question is do you disagree with Mendl's quote.

I disagree with using differtials for a process path that is irreversible since S and U are defined only for equilibrium states, and the states along an irreversible path are non-equilibrium.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ChetMiller since it appears that is what Mendl is doing, then I take it you do disagree with his statement, Is that correct?

I agree with him if the d’s are replaced by Deltas, the reservoir is at T, and the change is between equilibrium end states.

@ChetMiller In addition to replacing the d's with Deltas, wouldn't he also have to delete the word "infinitesimal"?

Using d’s is the same as infinitescimal.
